# SSL write err:5, errno 145, Connection timed out

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ssl

everyone:
        Just now, I got a problem with my code.

> I got a "SSL write err:5, errno 145, Connection timed out" error,

and this error doesn't show up frequently. We test the code about one month and this error just show up once.
        I search the error on Google, and I got nothing useful.
        Does anyone who had met this error?

```
// Below are my codes
int err, r;
int width = sockfd + 1;
struct timeval tv_timeout = {1,0};
fd_set writefds;
FD_ZERO(&writefds);

FD_SET(sockfd, &writefds);        

r = select(width, NULL, &writefds, 0, &tv_timeout);
if (r < 0) 
{
    printf("sslWriteData:r < 0\n");
    return FAIL;
}

if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &writefds))
{
    FD_CLR(sockfd, &writefds);
    r = SSL_write(pssl, (void*)(pszDataBuf + iBufLen - iLeftLen), iLeftLen)         
    err = SSL_get_error(pssl, r);
    if (SSL_ERROR_NONE == err)
    {
        //...;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("sslWriteData:SSL write err:%d, "
                "errno %d, %s\n", 
                err, errno, strerror(errno));
        return FAIL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there was a temporary network problem; hard to say for sure however, if you cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I thought it was a temporary network problem, but it took 16 minutes to timeout, not 1 second as I set by using select. That was weired.